# SCCM migration to SCCM 2012

Tags: sccm, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010, sccm-2012, sccm-2007

I am trying to plan a migration from SCCM 2007 to SCCM 2012. I am unable to find if I can migrate the Forefront from SCCM 2007 in SCCM 2012, or if I will have to uninstall all agents and install new 2012 agents.

If anybody has any information / experiences I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is Endpoint Protection 20102 is integrated into Configuration Manager 2012—it's no longer a separate piece. When you deploy Endpoint Protection 2012 from Configuration Manager, it will remove existing AV solutions, including previous versions of Forefront. See here:

[About Client Settings in Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acd0c29-e453-4863-8194-e479263291c8#BKMK_EndpointProtectionDeviceSettings)

I would assume you would need to recreate the Endpoint Protection Managed settings but am not sure (we used McAfee previously).

Comment: Bryan, 
  I believe you are correct, for more supporting evidence I finally stumbled across this link:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/FCSNext/thread/c4d9c34b-bad3-4684-b149-f51e960ce081

Which basically says that if you update your SCCM agent to 2012, You cannot use FEP from 2007.